# Consuming F# generic operators in C#

Tags: c#, generics, f#, operator-overloading

Since C# doesn't support generic operator overloads, I tried F#. I have the following F# code which seems to produce the overloads that I want

```ml
type Value<'T>() =
    static member ( + ) (lhs: Value<int>, rhs: Value<int>) = lhs
    static member ( + ) (lhs: Value<decimal>, rhs: Value<int>) = lhs;
```

but consuming it from C# doesn't go as planned:

```cs
Value<decimal> decimalValue = null;
Value<int> intValue = null;

var intResult = intValue + intValue; // works fine :)
var decimalResult = decimalValue + intValue; // Error CS0034 Operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Value<decimal>' and 'Value<int>'
```

I know a little about [statically resolved type parameters](https://theburningmonk.com/2011/12/f-inline-functions-and-member-constraints/) which may resolve the issue, but I don't want to use them because I need to carefully control the operations which are applied (e.g. I don't want to support adding strings and numbers).

Why is the call ambiguous? What can I do to resolve it?